# How do I change channel specific permissions on discord.py without overwriting the previous ones?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm able to update my channel permissions with:

```
geral_id = 906350388440092798
sessao_id = 906341908460548210
canal_geral = client.get_channel(geral_id)
canal_sessao = client.get_channel(sessao_id)
            
role = get(guild.roles, name="Role Name")
await canal_sessao.set_permissions(role, send_messages = False)
```

However, this completely removes all other role permissions from my channels.

How can I just update it without overwriting the other ones? Since it's just one permission, I am sure there is a way to do it without having to manually set all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

```py
channel = any_channel  # specify channel here
role = any_role  # specify role here
overwrites = channel.overwrites
role_overwrites = overwrites.get(role, discord.PermissionOverwrite())
role_overwrites.send_messages = False
overwrites[role] = role_overwrites
await channel.edit(overwrites=overwrites)
```